# How do I update the current row?

Tags: html, jquery

I have a addRow button which dynamically add rows to a table.

```
$("#addRow").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:    "php/insertPersonnel.php",
        type:   "POST",
        dataType:"JSON",
        data: {
            firstName:      $("#addPersonnelFirstName").val(),
            lastName:       $("#addPersonnelLastName").val(),
            emailAddress:   $("#addPersonnelEmailAddress").val(),
            jobTitle:       $("#addPersonnelJobTitle").val(),
            departmentID:   $("#selectPersonnelDepartment").val()
        },
        success: function (result) {
                var markup = "";
                markup += '<tr>';
                markup += '<td>' + result.data[0].firstName + result.data[0].lastName + result.data[0].jobTitle+ result.data[0].email + '</td>';
                markup += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editPersonnelBtn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editPersonnelModal" data-id = '+result.data[0].id+'> <i class="fa-solid fa-pencil fa-fw"> </i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm deletePersonnelBtn" data-bs-toggle ="modal" data-bs-target="#deletePersonnelModal" data-id= '+ result.data[0].id+ '> <i class="fa-solid fa-trash fa-fw"></i> </td>';
                markup += '</tr>';
                $("#personnelTable").append(markup);
                }
    }); 

    document.getElementById("addPersonnelForm").reset();    
});
```

This is the edit modal which has the values and was wondering how do I use these values to replace the current row values.

```
$("#editPersonnelModal").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
    $.ajax({
    url:"php/getPersonnelByID.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      id:$(e.relatedTarget).attr("data-id")// Retrieves the data-id attribute from the calling button
    },
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result)
      var resultCode = result.status.code;

      if (resultCode == 200) {
        // Update the hidden input with the employee id so that
        // it can be referenced when the form is submitted

        $("#editPersonnelEmployeeID").val(result.data.personnel[0].id);
        $("#editPersonnelFirstName").val(result.data.personnel[0].firstName);
        $("#editPersonnelLastName").val(result.data.personnel[0].lastName);
        $("#editPersonnelJobTitle").val(result.data.personnel[0].jobTitle);
        $("#editPersonnelEmailAddress").val(result.data.personnel[0].email);
        $("#editPersonnelDepartment").html("");

     }
   }
 })
```

})

I have a edit button that allows the user to modify the user values.

```
$(".editPersonnelBtn").on("click", function (e) {
    var $rowToUpdate = $(this).closest("tr");

})
```

After I have managed to retrieve the row which has been selected I don't know how to edit the current row and replace it with new values. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your missing an identifier.  Right now, there's nothing in your code to let your backend know which record you are trying to modify.  If you were to submit any changes, this script would call `php/insertPersonnel.php` via `POST`.

The code snippet, as currently provided, would provide everything you need for creating a record.  To be able to edit an existing record, you'll need to provide an immutable identifier, often a table id (though I prefer a UUID myself) that is a hidden input field.

If you want to reuse what you currently have within `php/insertPersonnel.php`, you'll have to add logic to check for the table id and do an update instead of an insert.

If you want to go full [CRUD](https://www.codecademy.com/article/what-is-crud), you can switch the call from `POST` to `PUT` (or `PATCH`).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".editPersonnelBtn").on("click", function (e) {
  var $rowToUpdate = $(this).closest("tr");
})
```

-- binds the event to the elements that are present at the time the event is created. To get around this, use:

````js
$(document).on('click', '.editPersonnelBtn', function(){
  // ...
})```
````

Comment: Please have a look at the updated code. How would I go about updating the current row values with the values that need to be displayed for the corresponding row.

Comment: Maybe when you provide a minimal reproducible example, I can help you. For now, your question is closed.